# React fetch API based on Product ID

Tags: reactjs

I want to display api data based on networkProductId. My first console returns me networkProductId  . When I check the networkProductId value inside fetchAPIDetails function it shows empty.

I am not getting correct API response

```
function NetworkProductInfo(props) {
  const { networkProductId } = props.state;
//console.log(networkProductId, 'networkProductId') 

  const [apiDataAccountList, setApiDataAccountList] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPIDetails(networkProductId)
  }, [])

  async function fetchAPIDetails(networkProductId) {
    const response = await networkProductsService.getNetworkProductById(networkProductId);
   // console.log(response, networkProductId, 'response productId fetchAPIDetails from product info')
    setApiDataAccountList(response.data)
  };



return (
 <Grid className={"text-field"}>
              <TextField
                label={
                  <span>
                    Client ID <span className={"label-required"}>*</span>
                  </span>
                }
                variant="outlined"
                className={"field"}
                size="small"
                id="clientId"
                path={clientId.path}
                value={clientId.value}
                helperText={clientId.errorMsg}
                error={clientId.errorMsg ? true : false}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  onFieldChange(clientId.path, e.target.value);
                  fetchAccountDetails(e.target.value);
                }}
                onBlur={() => {
                  if (networkProductId) {
                    fetchAPIDetails(networkProductId);
                  }

                  console.log(networkProductId, 'networkProductId')
                }}

              />
            </Grid>

 <ProductIdAccountList {...props}>
)

}
```